# is improper insert to nested map will make the new binary search tree under the map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I saw the sample code of one guy, he used the nested map for storing in to container.

```
 map< int,map<int,int> > outer_map;

ins_test[5].insert(make_pair<int,int>(5,6));
```

In above insertion to map,

the reference to `map<int,int>` will be returned on this part `ins_test[5]` and `(reference).insert();`
makes the insert to `map<int,int>`.

If my understanding of above is correct, then the new binary search tree will be formed by keeping the reference as root node.

Also consider if do insertion like this `outer_map.insert()` Then here another one binary search tree will be formed by keeping the 1st element inserted as root.

Is my understanding of above two points is correct?

If so, is it valid to do so because one of my friend done this model.

sample code

```
int main()
{
   using namespace std;

   map< int,map<int,int> > outer_map;

   outer_map[10].insert(make_pair<int,int>(1,2));
   outer_map[20].insert(make_pair<int,int>(3,4));
   outer_map[20].insert(make_pair<int,int>(5,6));


   map<int,int>  :: iterator in_iter ;
   map<int, map<int,int> > :: iterator out_iter;


   out_iter = outer_map.find(10);

   if(out_iter != outer_map.end())
   {
      printf("\n (out_iter->second).size :: %d ", (out_iter->second).size());
      for(in_iter =  (out_iter->second).begin() ; in_iter != (out_iter->second).end(); in_iter++ )
      {
         printf("\n Found");
      }
   }
  printf("\n out_map.size :: %d ", outer_map.size() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by " then the new binary search tree will be formed by keeping the reference as root node."? I really don't get what you are asking, just that if something with nested maps is valid to do. I don't see anything immediate "invalid" in your code.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a `map` is implemented as a tree.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem to me. What are you really trying to accomplish? I'm not going to go quite so far as to say that your `map<int, map<int, int>>` can't *possibly* be useful, but at first glance it seems like there's a good chance there's a better way to accomplish your real goal.